# TemplateDoesNotExist at /groups/ .....groups/group_base.html; Template-loader postmortem

Tags: python, django

i keep getting this error:

```
    TemplateDoesNotExist at /groups/ 
    
    groups/group_base.html

Template-loader postmortem
    
    Error during template rendering
```

As a note, this is from a tutorial wherein the tutorial is using an older version of django and python but I am using the latest version of each.

it seems to have a problem at the first line of group_base.html:

{% extends "groups/group_base.html" %}

here is the group_base.html

simplesocial/groups/templates/groups/group_base.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {% block pregroup %}{% endblock %}
      {% block group_content %}{% endblock %}
      {% block postgroup %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

idk if the problem is n the urls.py:

simplesocial/groups/templates/urls.py

```
#GROUPS URL.PY

from django.conf.urls import url
from groups import views

app_name = 'groups'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.ListGroups.as_view(), name='all'),
    url(r'^new/$', views.CreateGroup.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'^posts/in/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.SingleGroup.as_view(), name='single'),
    url(r'^join/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.JoinGroup.as_view(), name='join'),
    url(r'^leave/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.LeaveGroup.as_view(), name='leave'),
]
```

or if it's in views:

simplesocial/groups/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import (LoginRequiredMixin,
                                        PermissionRequiredMixin)


from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from groups.models import Group, GroupMember
# from groups import models

class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('name', 'description') #This is related to the Group model
    model = Group

class SingleGroup(generic.DetailView):
    model = Group

class ListGroups(generic.ListView):
    model = Group

class JoinGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single',kwargs={'slug':self.kwargs.get('slug')})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = get_object_or_404(Group, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        try:
            GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user, group=group) #this group is linked to the group instantiated above.
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.warning(self.request, 'Warning already a member!')
        else:
            messages.success(self.request,'You are now a member!')

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

class LeaveGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single',kwargs={'slug':self.kwargs.get('slug')})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # membership = models.GroupMember.objects.filter(
            membership = GroupMember.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user,
                group__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')
            ).get()
        #except models.GroupMember.DoesNotExist:
        except GroupMember.DoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, 'Sorry, you are not in this group!')
        else:
            membership.delete()
            messages.success(self.request, 'You have left the group')
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

here is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/groups/

Django Version: 3.1.1
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'accounts',
 'groups',
 'posts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/homepage/Desktop/My_Django_Stuff/simple_social_clone/simplesocial/templates/groups/group_base.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/groups/group_base.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/groups/group_base.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bootstrap3/templates/groups/group_base.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/homepage/Desktop/My_Django_Stuff/simple_social_clone/simplesocial/accounts/templates/groups/group_base.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/homepage/Desktop/My_Django_Stuff/simple_social_clone/simplesocial/groups/templates/groups/group_base.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/homepage/Desktop/My_Django_Stuff/simple_social_clone/simplesocial/posts/templates/groups/group_base.html (Source does not exist)


Template error:
In template /Users/homepage/Desktop/My_Django_Stuff/simple_social_clone/simplesocial/groups/templates/groups/group_list.html, error at line 1
   groups/group_base.html
   1 :  {% extends "groups/group_base.html" %} 
   2 : 
   3 : {% block pregroup %}
   4 :   <div class="col-md-4">
   5 :     <div class="content">
   6 :       {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   7 :         <h2>Welcome Back!
   8 :           <a href="{% url 'posts:for_user' username=user.username %}">
   9 :             @{{user.username}}
   10 :           </a>
   11 :         </h2>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 127, in render
    compiled_parent = self.get_parent(context)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 124, in get_parent
    return self.find_template(parent, context)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 103, in find_template
    template, origin = context.template.engine.find_template(
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 129, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name, tried=tried)

The above exception (groups/group_base.html) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 202, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 63, in render
    reraise(exc, self.backend)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 84, in reraise
    raise new from exc

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /groups/
Exception Value: groups/group_base.html
```

thnx

Answer (score 0):

In line 1 of `group_list.html` try using:

`{% extends "group_base.html" %}`

And tell me if it works.

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /groups/

Comment: i solved the problem, i named the file group_base_html instead of group_base.html